# what's wrong with this HQL query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a ManyToMany relationship between `Utilisateur` and `Projet` and I want to extract all users not existing in the project entity and the users assigned to a "Terminé" (value of statut:`Projet` property) project then this is my query:

```
select u from Utilisateur u left join u.projets p where p is null and  p.statut like 'Terminé'
```

generated sql query :

```
Hibernate: select utilisateu0_.iduser as iduser5_, utilisateu0_.datederniereconnexion as datedern2_5_, utilisateu0_.email as email5_, utilisateu0_.grade as grade5_, utilisateu0_.login as login5_, utilisateu0_.mdp as mdp5_, utilisateu0_.nomuser as nomuser5_, utilisateu0_.tel as tel5_ from 
public.utilisateur utilisateu0_ left outer join projet_utilisateur projets1_ on 
utilisateu0_.iduser=projets1_.utilisateurs_iduser left outer join public.projet projet2_ on 
projets1_.projets_idprojet=projet2_.idprojet where (projet2_.idprojet is null) and 
(projet2_.statut like 'Terminé')
```

This is my `Projet` Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Projet implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "idprojet", nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    Integer idprojet;

    String statut;

    @ManyToMany(
        mappedBy="projets", 
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Utilisateur> utilisateurs;
}
```

and this is the `Utilisateur` Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "iduser", nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    Integer iduser;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        schema = "public", 
        name = "join_membre_projet", 
        joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(
                name = "iduser", 
                referencedColumnName = "iduser", 
                nullable = false, 
                updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(
                name = "idprojet", 
                referencedColumnName = "idprojet", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    List<Projet> projets;

}
```

the problem is it does not show any user

Comment: you are selecting the table alias instead of any columns in your select statement. It should be something like `U.ColumnName` instead of just `U` in your select statement.

Comment: `left join u.projets p` doesn't look right either and if it is you are missing the `ON` statement.  Can you show us your table structure so we can better help you?

Comment: I don't see how that query works at all.  The Hibernate query is different than the one you posted.  But the biggest problem I see is you're `outer join`.  You're joining on idprojet, but then checking for it to be null, and then checking for another field in the same table to be equal to some value...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much with the hibernate, but something is wrong with your `HQL` code.  Are you sure you want the `OUTER JOIN` and `null` check?  Try removing those as they are negating ` p.statut like 'Terminé'`.

Comment: i want to extract users that not have any project and also users that have a project where the statut of this project is "Terminé"

Comment: @AM -- then I think you want `OR` instead of `AND`...

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments: *I want to extract users that not have any project and also users that have a project where the statut of this project is "Terminé"*

I think you want to use `OR` instead of `AND` in your `WHERE` criteria:

```
select u 
from Utilisateur u 
    left join u.projets p 
where p is null 
    or p.statut = 'Terminé'
```